# HTML Canvas Animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I want to create an animated canvas, which is also using a path.
I wrote this code by combining two scripts: [script1](https://dev.to/jordienr/how-to-make-animated-gradients-like-stripe-56nh) and [script2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill).

The script throws an exception: Failed to execute 'fill' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value '256' is not a valid enum value of type CanvasFillRule.

What can be wrong?

```js
            const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const r = new Path2D();
              r.moveTo(0, 0);
              r.lineTo(800, 0);
              r.lineTo(800, 200);
              r.lineTo(0, 400);
              r.lineTo(0, 0);
              r.closePath();

            let time = 0;

            const color = function (x, y, r, g, b) {
                context.fillStyle = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
                context.fill(r);
            }
            const R = function (x, y, time) {
                return (Math.floor(191 + 64 * Math.cos((x * x - y * y) / 300 + time)));
            }

            const G = function (x, y, time) {
                return (Math.floor(191 + 64 * Math.sin((x * x * Math.cos(time / 4) + y * y * Math.sin(time / 3)) / 300)));
            }

            const B = function (x, y, time) {
                return (Math.floor(191 + 64 * Math.sin(5 * Math.sin(time / 9) + ((x - 100) * (x - 100) + (y - 100) * (y - 100)) / 1100)));
            }

            const startAnimation = function () {
                for (x = 0; x <= 30; x++) {
                    for (y = 0; y <= 30; y++) {
                        color(x, y, R(x, y, time), G(x, y, time), B(x, y, time));
                    }
                }
                time = time + 0.03;
                window.requestAnimationFrame(startAnimation);
            }

            startAnimation();
```

```css
        body {
            height: 400px;
            width: 500px;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="32px" height="32px">
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are exceeding the bounds of a color value required in the `rgb()` function.

Valid numbers are 0-255

You will need to modify `R()`, `G()`, and `B()`

After the result is calculated in any of those functions, subtract 1 from it before returning.

***EDIT:**** The bounds of color values needed to be fixed, but it wasn’t the main issue.

The problem is that you create a path and name the variable `r`

Inside the color function, you take `r` as a parameter.

When you call `fill`, the value for Red is being passed, not the path itself.

Change your path variable to something other than `r` and you’ll be golden.

Comment: I modified the 192 in 191, and the error still persists: The provided value '255' is not a valid enum value of type CanvasFillRule. I think is something related to a CanvasFillRule.

Comment: I found the issue. Updating answer.